The problem is encountered while debugging on windows 'SendEmailVerificationBeforeUpdatingEmail': is not a member of 'firebase::auth::User'
The problem is encountered while debugging on windows how can fix this issue on my project, I changed my FirebaseAuth latest  version but there no changes. This project running two devices but Android debugging, no errors encountered

Verify that you are using the SendEmailVerificationBeforeUpdatingEmail method as stipulated in the documentation, with the required parameter.
